# A prime number of the form $10^n+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers $n$ and prime $p$  such that

> $$10^n+1=p$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with the context in which you encountered the problem, and with your thoughts on how to approach it. We will be happy then to guide you with hints and suggestions.

Comment: In the comments to http://oeis.org/A000533 it is said that the only two $n$ less than $100000$ are $1,2$, giving $11,101$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably , the only primes of the form $$10^n+1$$ are $2,11$ and $101$. If there is another such prime, the exponent must be a power of $2$ and exceed $10^6$

Look at this site for factors and the current status :

http://factordb.com/index.php?query=10%5E2%5En%2B1&use=n&n=1&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&FF=on&PRP=on&CF=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=20&format=1&sent=Show

Comment: $10^8+1$ is also prime

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Maybe, you mix that with $2^8+1$ ? We have $17\mid 10^8+1$

Comment: Yes, it's divisible by $17$.

Comment: But how to prove that $10^{2^n}+1$ is composite for all $n\geq2$?

Comment: A proof almost surely is out of reach. But the chances to get a further prime decreases drastically after every doubling of the exponent.

Comment: It's interesting that sometimes it's divisible by the prime Fermat $2^{2^n}+1$

Comment: The prime factors must be of the form $$k\cdot 2^{n+1}+1$$ so far small enough exponents, a Fermat prime can be a prime factor.

Comment: Yes, it's true for $F_n$, but why it's true for our numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89516/discussion-between-peter-and-michael-rozenberg).